# Exporting Illustrator SVG for web, using shape or line?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have been working on several icons for my startup but I want to know if it's better to export them as a shape or a line.  Is there a difference between exporting the SVG in an expanded shape or a simpler line path?

Comment: Are you asking the difference between saving as an image ".svg" or as inline code? What do you mean shape or line?

Comment: Im asking the difference between exporting the svg in an expanded shape or a simpler line path.

Comment: I am still a little confused on what you mean. When you say expanded shape. Do you mean all shapes expanded (object -> expand) vs non expanded shapes? What do you mean by line path? Are you just saying a stroke? Just know that the more objects you have from your graphic the more data points will be used to create the svg.

Comment: Linking to one of your svg files would help us better understand your question.  The purpose of the export might also be relevant - what's your end goal here?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the SVG.

If you are going to be animating it and using it inline, it is better to export it in the format that would be easier to animate. If you are simply using it as an image, you should export it in the format that saves the smallest. It doesn't really matter to the browser, and you shouldn't be seeing it any differently either way. My suggestion would be to export it how you finished it in the vector program you are using.

SVG is very powerful, and if you were planning on using CSS or animations, then the way you export IS important, but I can't say which is better without more information.